# SDL_net no opengl context has been made

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-net

I'm following a tutorial on SDL_net and am quite confused on why my program is crashing. You can find the tutorial [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJfC4-yNnzY) My client crashes after running it with the server open.

I'm just wondering what this error means (using SDLNet_GetError()):

```
no opengl context has been made
```

I'm just working off core SDL with SDL_TTF and have no idea what this means. The tutorial example I followed used OpenGL so if I were to guess the error is to do with me not using it? I just assumed it only required SDL.

If you want a look at the code you can find the [client code here](http://pastebin.com/7vc6wq9t), and the [server code here](http://pastebin.com/pw9TQcqW). I'm not going to put it all in this question as it's rather long and I'd be fine with just a simple explanation of the error, I don't want to ask for a full explanation to what's wrong with my code.

Okay, so my initialization code is done through a ScreenManager:

```
#include "ScreenManager.h"

ScreenManager &ScreenManager::GetInstance(){
    static ScreenManager instance;
    return instance;
}

void ScreenManager::init(){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    TTF_Init();
    SDLNet_Init();

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1920, 1080, SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, 0, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    running = true;

    ResourceManager::GetInstance().loadTexture(renderer, "res/Human.bmp", "player");
    ResourceManager::GetInstance().loadTexture(renderer, "res/space.bmp", "background");
    ResourceManager::GetInstance().loadTexture(renderer, "res/ship.bmp", "ship");
    ResourceManager::GetInstance().loadTexture(renderer, "res/interior.bmp", "interior");

    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

    GameManager::GetInstance().init();

    currentScreen = new MainScreen();
    currentScreen->init();
}

void ScreenManager::close(){
    ResourceManager::GetInstance().close();
    currentScreen->close();

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);

    SDL_Quit();
    SDLNet_Quit();
    TTF_Quit();
}

void ScreenManager::update(){
    currentScreen->update();
}

void ScreenManager::render(){
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    currentScreen->render(renderer);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void ScreenManager::setScreen(GameScreen *screenToSet){
    currentScreen->close();
    currentScreen = screenToSet;
    currentScreen->init();
}

void ScreenManager::handleEvents(){
    SDL_Event e;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) > 0){
        switch(e.type){
            case SDL_QUIT:
                running = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

bool ScreenManager::isRunning(){
    return running;
}
```

Which is running a screen, this is where the network runs:

```
#include "MainScreen.h"

void MainScreen::init(){
    Network = new network();
    Network->init();

    player = new Player((1920 / 2) - 32, (1080 / 2) - 32);
    background = new Background();
    entity_vector.push_back(new Ship(30, 30, 699*4, 444*4, 0, "ship", "interior"));
}

void MainScreen::close(){
    Network->close();
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < entity_vector.size(); i++){
        entity_vector[i]->close();
    }
    player->close();
}

void MainScreen::update(){
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < entity_vector.size(); i++){
        entity_vector[i]->update();
    }
    player->update((1920 / 2) - 32, (1080 / 2) - 32);

    GameManager::GetInstance().update();
    Network->recv(enemies, player);
    Network->send(player);
}

void MainScreen::render(SDL_Renderer *renderer){
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < entity_vector.size(); i++){
        entity_vector[i]->render(renderer);
    }
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++){
        enemies[i]->render(renderer);
    }
    background->render(renderer);
    player->render(renderer);
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could indicate which program crashes (server or client?), and at which line.

Comment: It's my client, fixed my question in an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not creating an OpenGL context anywhere and call `SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);` which according to the [source](http://fossies.org/linux/SDL2/src/video/SDL_video.c) sets the error to `No OpenGL context has been made current`. And then in your `void network::send(Player *p)` you call `SDLNet_GetError()` for no apparent reason and get that error. I assume you should call [SDL_GL_CreateContext](http://fossies.org/linux/SDL2/src/video/SDL_video.c) after `SDL_CreateWindow`.

Comment: I assumed that this would fix the crash I get, I was being naive. Any idea what could be behind the crash? I certainly don't.

Comment: Well, to be honest mostly I try and help out but at the moment I don't have any time to devote to this. Your code has a lot of `new` calls and pointers and looking at it takes time. I don't wan't to sound impolite, but why can't you use a debugger? At least a stack trace of the point of crash would help.

Comment: @genfy I took a quick look at the client code you posted and well - you need to rework it a lot. Sorry for the criticism but it is terrible - you are using a global `tmp` (assuming global since there is no declaration or definition) which is being printed to and accessed in weird ways like `tmp[strlen(tmp - 1)]` (I am calling this weird because you will actually pass one byte before the start of `tmp` to `strlen`). There are just too many things that could go wrong.